# Bash script dont capture traffic from tcpdump in background

Tags: bash

I wrote a script to record traffic in MySQL.

Here is the code.

```
#!/bin/bash

elements=()

i=0
/usr/sbin/tcpdump -i vlan100 host 172.10.100.233 and port 80 -qnnp -vvvs 1500 -l -A | grep -oE "(GET|POST|HEAD) .* HTTP/1.[01]|Host: .*" | while read element; do
    elements[$i]=$element
    if [[ $element =~ 'Host:' ]]; then
    /usr/bin/php /home/report/tcp_dump.php ${elements[$(($i-1))]} ${elements[$i]} >> /home/report/tcp_dump_sql.log
    fi

    i=$(($i+1))
done
```

Packets look like:

> tcpdump: listening on vlan100, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture
>   size 1500 bytes
>
> 10 packets captured  13 packets received by filter  0 packets dropped
>   by kernel
>
> GET /posts/26848300 HTTP/1.1
>     Host: stackoverflow.com
>
> GET / HTTP/1.1
>   Host: stackoverflow.com

If i start this script from command line - everything good. Script capture packets and send it php file, which writes to SQL DB.

If script start from crontab - script work, but tcpdump dont capture packets.

I think the problem is in code with tcpdump function. It not captured packets when it starts from crontab.

Where is the problem?

Comment: If the problem is actually that `tcpdump` doesn't capture any data (and not that the script fails to run because `php` isn't in the default path or `tcpdump` fails to run because it isn't) then you should ensure that the user running the cron job is allowed to capture traffic on that device.

Comment: User is root. I think all good whith rools. where i can check this?

Comment: Does your php script get run at all? Do you see output from tcpdump about packets captured when you kill the process? If you add `set -x` to the script do you see the commands being run the way you expect them to be run?

Comment: If bash scripts starts from crontab - php command dont work. As i understand it tcpdump dont capture packets and script misses the cycle.

Comment: I don't know that I understood that. You need to find out which command(s) in that script is/are having problems when run via cron. It could be `tcpdump`; it could be `php`; it could be a `PATH` problem; it could be a device permissions issue. Without more information about what is failing we can't help. Try adding some debugging output (that `set -x` I suggested and/or some plain `echo`/`printf` calls in various parts of the script and see what you get.

Comment: I shure - its tcpdump command which dont capture packets when it starts via cron.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely `PHP` is not in the default `CRON` path. Check the cron file you're using to start the script and make sure that you set the `PATH` variable so that it includes the location of the `php` binary.

Comment: PHP works good. problem in tcpdump, which dont work in background.

Comment: and is `tcpdump` in the path? try running `which tcpdump` and compare it with `$PATH` in your cron file

Comment: Put `>/tmp/log 2>&1` to the end of the cron entry line to get a logfile in `/tmp/log`. Check if there's any meaningful error message there